# Convert non-numeric data in a vector to the value that they're trying to represent

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

Part of my data was captured like: "20 minutes"(character) instead of just 20 (integer). The data set is quite large and several vectors have this same problem, so doing it by hand will take too long.

ex.

```
HoursExer <- c(1, 2, 2, "2 hours", 3, "1h30", "90minutes", 0)
```

Desired output

```
[1] 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 1.5 1.5 0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may sound easy, but due to the many different possibilities, this may take more work than you'd think. Below the solution you'll find a general explanation and the definitions of the functions for the different patterns

**Solution:** After defining all patterns and transformations, we can transform your dirty data to a nicely structured vector where all data is in the same way:

```
vec <- c(1, 2, 2, "2 hours", 3, "1h30", "90minutes", 0, "1hour")

vec[hrs]     <- hrs_trans(vec[hrs])
vec[hrs_alt] <- hrs_alt_trans(vec[hrs_alt])
vec[min]     <- min_trans(vec[min])
vec          <- as.numeric(vec)
# [1] 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 1.5 1.5 0.0 1.0
```

**General idea**:
For every pattern like `1h30`, `2 hours`, `90 minutes`, `3 mins` you will need to:

1. Detect whether we're dealing with minutes or hours.
2. Extract the relevant information according to some similar structure.

I think the best tool to use here is [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (also known as regex). I'll discuss some of patterns I think you may encounter in your data:

**Pattern 1**: `2 hours`, `1 hour`, `4hours`

```
# Detect the positions in `vec` that has strings containing "hour":
hrs <- grep(pattern = "hour", vec)

# Extracts the number from a string. If
hrs_trans <- function(string){
  number  <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", string)
  return(number)
}
hrs_trans("15 hours")
# [1] "15"
```

**Pattern 2:** `1h30`, `4H45`

```
# Detect "numbers" + "h or H" + "numbers" pattern
hrs_alt <- grep(pattern = "[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]", vec)

# 
hrs_alt_trans <- function(string){
  hrs_loc  <- gregexpr("([0-9]{1,2})(?=[hH])", string, perl=T)
  mins_loc <- gregexpr("((?<=[hH])([0-9]{1,2}))", string, perl=T)
  hrs  <- as.numeric(regmatches(string, hrs_loc)[[1]])
  mins <- as.numeric(regmatches(string, mins_loc)[[1]])
  return(hrs + (mins/60))
}
hrs_alt_trans("5H15")
# [1] "5.25"
```

**Pattern 3:** `15 minutes`, `10min`, `75mins`

```
# Detect positions:
min <- grep(pattern = "min", vec)

# Extract the number of minutes and transform to hours:
min_trans <- function(string){
  mins <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", string)
  hrs  <- as.numeric(mins)/60
  return(hrs)
}
min_trans("60 minutes") 
# [1] 1
```